# Serving HTML application when offline

Tags: php, html

I am writing an application to use even when offline. I tried the HTML5 manifest(which is now deprecated) and also opted to use 'Service Workers' but my application is a local intranet web page which cannot be served as HTTPS currently due to restrictions.

Can you advice me on how I can architect the webpage? I am hosting the application on IIS and it needs to be used on mobile devices when both offline and online. I am using PHP for backend

Would appreciate some guidance on this. I went through some of the previous answers and tried them but none fits my requirements. Is there any other way I can make the application served offline?

Comment: "cannot be served as HTTPS currently due to restrictions" — Fix those restrictions.

Comment: Quentin, Thanks, wish it could be that easy. Is there any other alternative for local intranet based sites?

Comment: You could setup your own CA server and add the certificate as trusted on the clients to solve the https problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, we resolved to lifting restrictions on the server to allow https connections locally on our network. This fixed my requirement